# Creating a data frame use loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am new to python and trying be more efficient with my coding. The current problem i have is to use loop to simplify the following code. Currently this code works as expected, but I have too many models to save with different ranges.

```
keyword = pd.DataFrame(
    Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[-1]["Topic"]),
    columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
)

keyword['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == -1")['Name']
keyword['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == -1")['Count']
keyword['Topic number'] = '-1'
```

```
keyword0 = pd.DataFrame(
   Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[0]["Topic"]), 
   columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
)

keyword0['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Name']
keyword0['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Count']
keyword0['Topic number'] = '0'
keyword_all = keyword.append(keyword0)
```

```
keyword1 = pd.DataFrame(
   Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[1]["Topic"]), 
   columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
)

keyword1['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Name']
keyword1['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Count']
keyword1['Topic number'] = '1'
keyword_all = keyword.append(keyword1)
```

```
keyword2 = pd.DataFrame(
   Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[2]["Topic"]), 
   columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
)

keyword2['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Name']
keyword2['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Count']
keyword2['Topic number'] = '2'
keyword_all = keyword.append(keyword2)
```

```
keyword3 = pd.DataFrame(
   Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[3]["Topic"]), 
   columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"])

keyword3['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Name']
keyword3['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Count']
keyword3['Topic number'] = '3'
keyword_all = keyword.append(keyword3)
```

```
keyword4 = pd.DataFrame(
   Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[4]["Topic"]), 
   columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
)

keyword4['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Name']
keyword4['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == 0")['Count']
keyword4['Topic number'] = '4'
keyword_all = keyword.append(keyword4)
```

I am hoping to change this code to something like:

```
for x in range(-1,4):keyword_x = pd.DataFrame(Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[x]["Topic"]), columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"])

keyword_x['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == x")['Name']
keyword_x['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query("Topic == x")['Count']
keyword_x['Topic number'] = x
keyword_x = df(keyword_x).append(df(keyword_x+1))

df.to_csv(SAVE_DIR + 'keyword_all_Q5_model.csv')
```

Comment: Don't name the variables `keyword0`, `keyword1`, etc.  Instead, store them in a list of dataframes called `keywords`.  Now, you can just append each new DF to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your process in a method with parameters. Then iteratively call the method via a list comprehension to be concatenated with [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) at end:

```py
def build_df(i)
    keyword = pd.DataFrame(
        Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[i]["Topic"]), 
        columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
    )

    keyword['Topic'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query(f"Topic == {i}")['Name']
    keyword['Count'] = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query(f"Topic == {i}")['Count']
    keyword['Topic number'] = str(i)

    return keyword


keyword_all_Q5_mode = pd.concat(
    [build_df(i) for i in range(-1, 5)], ignore_index = False
)
```

Shorter hand with [**`DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```py
def build_df(i)
    return (
        pd.DataFrame(
            Q5_model.get_topic(freq.iloc[i]["Topic"]), 
            columns = ["keyword","c-TF-IDF scores"]
        ).assign(
            Topic = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query(f"Topic == {i}")['Name'],
            Count = Q5_model.get_topic_info().query(f"Topic == {i}")['Count'],
            Topic_number = str(i)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, this works so beautifully!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!